# unable to authenticate using FreeRadius

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, freeradius

I deployed freeradius and radtest looks good for localhost but when I sent Access-Request from external server, FreeRadius server doesn't reply:

```
2023-11-29 13:49:26.675791 (1) Access-Request Id 20 ens160:172.20.252.242:32778 -> 142.244.0.47:1812 +0.000

2023-11-29 13:49:31.875791 (1) ** norsp ** Access-Request Id 20 ens160:172.20.252.242:32778 -> 142.244.0.47:1812

2023-11-29 13:49:36.680094 (2) Access-Request Id 21 ens160:172.20.252.242:32778 -> 142.244.0.47:1812 +10.004
```

Client config :

```
client wireless {
        ipaddr = 172.20.252.242
        secret = freeradius2023
        proto = *
        nastype = other
}
```

When I run `freeradius -X`, it doesn't help much.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.